# nextcloud onlyoffice integration Document Server [GetConvertedUri on check error, Error while downloading the document file to be converted]

Tags: nextcloud, onlyoffice

Versions : nextcloud v15, onlyoffice-DocumentServer v5.2,connector 2.4 onlyoffice and The servers are working on Centos 7.

- Works correctly without HTPPS
- Now I have the following error when integrating Document Server to NextCloud by HTTPS in the nextcloud logs:

> app "onlyoffice" Message "GetConvertedUri on check error: An error
>   occurred in the document service: Error while downloading the document
>   file to be converted." with
>
> app "onlyoffice" Message "Download empty without jwt"

nextcloud and onlyoffice-documentServers are configured by the same wildcard certificate and browsers accept it correctly

onlyoffice-DocumentServer logs:

```
[2019-07-29T13:26:40.160] [ERROR] nodeJS - error downloadFile:url=https://mydomain/index.php/apps/onlyoffic                                                                                                             e/empty?doc=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY3Rpb24iOiJlbXB0eSJ9.k09JPfgibOWBTZGmYfPU47O8HeUGh6Q_FHuUQYJRGY4                                                                                                   ;attempt=3;code:null;connect:null;(id=conv_check_908902956_docx)
Error: Error response: statusCode:403 ;body:
{"message":"Access denied"}
    at Request._callback (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/sources/utils.js:250:18)
    at Request.self.callback (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:                                                                                                                        1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

The document server works correctly if you work without authentication by token in http, but if I change the configuration to work by token it does not work.

I have tried the following configuration...

config.php Nexcloud add lines code:

```
'onlyoffice' =>
   array (
   'jwt_secret' => 'mysecret',
   'jwt_header' => 'test',
   ),
```

local.json OnlyOffice-DocumentServer add lines code:

```
"token": {
        "enable": {
          "request": {
            "inbox": true,
            "outbox": true
          },
          "browser": true
        },
        "inbox": {
          "header": "test"
        },
        "outbox": {
          "header": "test"
        }
      },
      "secret": {
        "inbox": {
          "string": "mysecret"
        },
        "outbox": {
          "string": "mysecret"
        },
        "session": {
          "string": "mysecret"
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ibnpetr, is true, what you say, the config.php doesn't need any configuration for additional ssl

now this Work it!

The problem is that the intermediate organization that issues the certificate does not automatically recognize it in the operating system as if it is chorme or mozilla and validates it, in this case you need to enter the entity’s certificate to its list to validate it if it is given If you do not have it, we check that with the wget command https: // if there is an error you have to do it manually as I said before.

Thankss

Answer (score 0):

> DocumentServer v5.2

We would recommend using the latest version of the DocumentServer (5.3.4.3)

Please try using default configuration of the DocumentServer without changing the header when enabling JWT.
You only need to specify the address of the DocumentServer and a secret in the NC admin panel (Settings -> Administration -> ONLYOFFICE)

Please do not forget to restart DocumentServer services after editing the local.json file:

```
supervisorctl restart all
```